# In Unity for Android and iOS, I had video playing in world space, but it stopped working suddenly, what could have caused this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, augmented-reality

```
try
            {
                string[] splitVidParams = { "0.0", "0.0", "0.1", "0.1" };
                if (vidParams != "")
                {
                    splitVidParams = vidParams.Split(';');
                }

                Debug.Log("init video");
                GameObject videoProjection = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
                VideoPlayer videoPlayer = videoProjection.AddComponent<VideoPlayer>();

                videoPlayer.playOnAwake = true;
                new Downloader().DownloadVideo(video, targetId);
                string videoSource = Application.persistentDataPath + "/importedModels/" + video;


                videoPlayer.url = videoSource;
                videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
                videoPlayer.isLooping = true;

                //Set render mode
                videoPlayer.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.MaterialOverride;
                GameObject instVideo = Instantiate(videoProjection, wrapper.transform);
                instVideo.transform.localScale = new Vector3(float.Parse(splitVidParams[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 0.1f, 0.1f, float.Parse(splitVidParams[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 0.1f);
                instVideo.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(float.Parse(splitVidParams[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 0f, float.Parse(splitVidParams[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

                Destroy(videoProjection);
                instVideo.name = "Video Player";
                instantiatedModels.Add(instVideo);
                MeshRenderer videoRenderer = instVideo.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
                instVideo.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(instVideo.transform.localEulerAngles.x, instVideo.transform.localEulerAngles.y + 180, instVideo.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogError(e.Message);
            }
```

This is the code i use, it used to work on both iOS and Android just fine. The video got downloaded and played. Old builds still work, but when i make a new build even from the old version of the whole thing, code included, it soesnt work either. It does work in play mode. And i have other parts which are downloaded at runtime and then loaded in and these work fine on both relevant platforms.
Android doenst even throw an error or exception even through the try-catch. iOS throws 'renderer "Video player", targeted by video player has no material with a texture property'.

I tried to update Unity AFTER this started happening and it didnt help, so i reverted back, i tried to source directly to the web URL without downloading and it still didnt work. I tried to just place a new video player into the space manually and give it the URL and that didnt work as well. Just shows the Plane in magenta color. WHich is not exactly what i want, but like i said, it does work fine in play mode.

Comment: It sounds like the material is the problem.  Try changing the material and see if that works.  Have you tried using a local video to see if the problem persists there?  It might provide some additional clues.

Comment: I tried even putting the video player into the hierarchy manually and used clip from a local video, once again works just fine in play mode, but still doesnt work on Android or iOS.